# Can I load a script only for the view that is being injected - Angular

Tags: angularjs

So, at the moment I have an index.html page that contains every single reference to all scripts I need (angular libraries, jquery libraries, third party plugins, custom javascripts, controllers, directives, services, etc). As you can see this is not ideal because the browser will load all of these dependencies when not all of them are really needed all the time.

Is there a way to load only the scripts needed by the view that is loaded? In the same fashion, these scripts must be removed when the view changes, and accept news if needed.

I've made a sample [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tDjlc6n8F1FQd9G8O5x5?p=preview) with some simple stuff representing my problem

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
   <body class="container">
         <div class="navbar">
           <div class="navbar-inner">
             <a class="brand" ui-sref="index">Sample</a>
             <ul class="nav">
               <li>
                 <a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a>
               </li>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="span12">
             <div class="well" ui-view></div>
           </div>
         </div>

         <!-- App Script -->
         <script src="app.js">  </script>
         <!-- This is what I have now and no likey-->
         <script src="script1.js">  </script>
         <script src="script2.js">  </script>
         <script src="script3.js">  </script>
         <script src="script4.js">  </script>
         <script src="script5.js">  </script>
         <script src="script6.js">  </script>
         <script src="script7.js">  </script>
         .
         .
         .             
         <script src="script100.js">  </script>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you'd be looking for a build/module mechanism of some kind? I've used Closure pretty extensively, there's also Webpack which is really popular. Does all kind of code inlining, dead code removal, and so on.

Comment: You can give it - https://oclazyload.readme.io/ a try - lazy loading for angular.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with lazy loading, it never was supported by Angular officially and may cause more troubles than solve. Lazy loading can't help with this requirement, *these scripts must be removed when the view changes, and accept news if needed*. That's wrong point of view, scripts can't be removed, once they were executed, they were. If they weren't written to run multiple times, they will make a mess.

Comment: So far I've added lazy load and followed their docs and not working for me. Now it keeps telling me Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'workspaceCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Well lazyloading definitely didn't do the trick. I was hopeful